# Chrome fonts in suggestion box of any text fields is bold

Tags: 15.10, google-chrome, fonts

All of a sudden, this happened to my PC.

[image]

As you could see, the suggestion box is suddenly in **bold**! I remember installing dependencies and libraries to my PC prior to this happening through `apt-get`, python's `pip` and other manual installations, but I'm not sure if it directly affected this; I also can't track which of them have possibly caused this.

Any ideas? Is it possibly a bug to Chrome's update's part?

Comment: Same problem after upgrading to 16.04